# While playing game, laptop runs hot and randomly disconnects mouse and keyboard

Tags: usb, dell-inspiron, nvidia-geforce

I have a Dell Inspiron 7577 laptop with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design running Windows 10, and I have my HDMI plugged in to an external monitor (which I wouldn't think is the problem), but when I play Guild Wars 2 and have it running for a bit, the top of the keyboard above the F keys are extremely hot , but the fan is running. Most days if I'm playing for more than an hour, the USB mouse and keyboard, **as well as** the onboard keyboard and touchpad will not respond to anything. The laptop doesn't freeze, the game graphics are still running and sometimes within about 30 seconds the mouse and keyboard will respond again.

- the mouse and keyboard haven't disconnected during moderate use, only high fan speed graphics, and it's random when it disconnects.
- Only happens during gaming.
- Nothing pops up on the taskbar that suggests that the usb has been disconnected or connected (like "Device is ready to use").
- Gaming is always done on 1 external HDMI monitor, if that makes a difference.
- I run the game in windowed mode.

What is happening?

Comment: Did you check the temperature (using CPUZ for example) when it happened? Maybe try to use a laptop cooler to see if it helps

Comment: Using CPUID I had Intel I/O 76C, Nvidia 74C, Package 91C, Core0 91C, Core1 88C, Core2 89C, Core3 79C

Comment: I think it's too hot. Maybe overheating caused that problem.

Comment: Rather than too hot, its possible that the device us running out of available power. Depending on the specific hardware there is a limited amount of power available within the machine, and it's possible the high-demand from the CPU and GPU are browning out the USB power. Check you've not got anything on USB you aren't using. If anything has the option of external power, rather than feeding from the USB, use the external power option.

Comment: Would that also "turn off" the touchpad and onboard keyboard though? because neither USB input devices or the touchpad and onboard keyboard work during these small "outages"